# When changing the project target framework, .net framework 4.8.1 is still not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have .net framework 4.8.1 on this website https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net481

But when I changed the project target framework, I still couldn't find .net framework 4.8.1.

[image]

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2022 and using Repair Visual Studio 2022 still does not work.

Comment: Can't you install 4.8.1 along with Visual Studio? After selecting .Net Desktop Development, select .NetFramework 4.8.1 development tools on the right sidebar.

Comment: ohhh! Thank you very much for the tip, I clicked on asp.net and web development. 4.8 is not found on the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Installer can install .net framework 4.8.1 directly.

When you use Visual Studio Installer to install .net framework 4.8.1, you need to uninstall the previously installed .net framework 4.8.1 first.

In Visual Studio Installer, in addition to clicking .Net Desktop Development, check .net framework 4.8.1 on the right side to install it.

[image]

You can also check .net framework 4.8.1 in the Individual component after entering the Visual Studio Installer to install it.

[image]

Comment: You can get to the Visual Studio installer to do this by selecting Tools/Get Tools and Features... from the menu.